# Android Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am facing this strange issue after factory reset of my Macbook.
Android studio is not able to build the project and showing the same issue every time I build.

Note: I have found various same threads on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me. Thats why I had to put it on stackoverflow.

[image]

Gradle console and Manifest Info can be found below:

Grandle Console Log:

```
[![Executing tasks: \[clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :utilities:generateDebugSources\]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
app: 'androidProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':utilities' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'debugCompile' in project ':utilities' is deprecated. Use 'debugImplementation' instead.
utilities: 'androidProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0' and apply the kapt plugin: "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'".

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:87)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:69)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:651)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:133)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:100)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:81)
    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:265)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.computeResourceSetList0(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:156)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.getResDirectories(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$3.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:172)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin$applyExperimental$3.invoke(AndroidSubplugin.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandlerKt$sam$Action$4ca85ddb.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.applyExperimental(AndroidSubplugin.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidSubplugin.apply(AndroidSubplugin.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.SubpluginEnvironment.addSubpluginOptions(KotlinPlugin.kt:794)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:629)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.access$processVariant(KotlinPlugin.kt:477)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:547)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2$1.invoke(KotlinPlugin.kt:477)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandlerKt$sam$Action$4ca85ddb.execute(Android25ProjectHandler.kt)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:136)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Android25ProjectHandler.forEachVariant(Android25ProjectHandler.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:546)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler$handleProject$2.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:477)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:469)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:461)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:437)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:865)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.access$2600(DefaultConfiguration.java:799)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1189)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.computeResourceSetList(MergeResources.java:664)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':utilities'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:87)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:69)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:651)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.evaluateProjectAndDiscoverTasks(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.beforeResolvingProjectDependency(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.beforeResolved(DefaultProjectDependency.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.addDependencies(DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.addDependencyDescriptors(DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultConfigurationComponentMetaDataBuilder.addConfigurations(DefaultConfigurationComponentMetaDataBuilder.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultConfiguration.java:690)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$DefaultResolveContextToComponentResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:66)
    ... 142 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /Users/akshay/Library/Android/sdk
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:166)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:171)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:718)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:600)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$3(BasePlugin.java:555)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:551)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
    ... 168 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s][1]][1]
```

build.gradle - Project Level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.61'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appsmartz.wallzypremiumwallpapers"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

ext.supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'
ext.firebaseVersion = '11.6.2'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibVersion"

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$firebaseVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$firebaseVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$firebaseVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebaseVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$firebaseVersion"

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularfillableloaders:1.2.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.2'
    //  compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'
    compile project(':utilities')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: this isn't an Android Studio question; It's about Gradle, specifically for Android. Questions about the IDE itself should be tagged [tag:android-studio], not questions about code *in* the IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using the same sdk version in the other modules.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since everything was right in my case, this had to be a gradle issue(bug probably). This happens mostly due to **implementation(project-lib)** part, probably when the project is added for the first time, or when due to any issue the project-lib module fails to build, and this error occurs in the subsequent tries to build the project, even if the issues are addressed.

I suppose there's some kind of cyclic dependency that triggers this. So the hack to go around this are the following steps.

**1.** Go to **build.gradle** inside **app** folder, and comment out the **implementation(project-lib)** dependency.

**2.** Press **Sync Now** on the option that appears after changing anything in gradle.
You don't get an error, good. You get one? Better. In any case proceed.

**3.** Go to the **Gradle** option on right side of the studio(look at the right edge) press it, click on main-project, you will see your project-lib option, click  it, then ->Tasks->Build->Assemble Debug and Assemble Release.

If you don't see your project-lib there, you have to delete all build folders and iml files manually, invalidate caches and restart. You will then see your project.

**4.** Uncomment the dependency line in your app level build.gradle, that you previously commented, and **DO NOT** press **Sync Now**. Go to -> Build-> Rebuild project. Then if the Sync now option is still there, you can sync.

Now the error will be gone.

**N.B** This answer is after you ensure, there are no loopholes from your side.

Answer (score 4):

### If this problem is popping on Flutter then,

Open your `build.gradle` file in *`android`* folder. (not in app)

inside `dependency` block, update **classpath** of `tools.build.gradle` like this,

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was fixed by using the latest version of Gradle. Change the gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties to the latest one found [here](https://gradle.org/releases/).

Answer (score 0):

Check   gradle version. gradle -v

Check gradle version and gradle plugin version compatible or Not

Example:

**gradle 4.6 is not compatible with gradle plugin 2.2.**

**so  update com.android.tools.build:gradle version to 2.3.3.**

then you need check gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl gradle version

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get a fix to the same problem.  I went into the Gradle window and look at the dependencies.  In my case when I looked at my buildSrc dependencies I noticed that the compileClassPath and the runtimeClassPath both used different versions of "org.jetbrain.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk". That focused me on looking at my root build.gradle.kts and my buildSrc build.gradle.kts and the two were using different versions of "org.gradle.kotlin:gradle-kotlin-dsl-plugins".  I corrected them to be the same version and this problem went away!  I suspect that this same problem could happen if you mismatch versions of other dependencies. So hopefully my explanation helps with an approach on how to find version mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

- Add properties to the `gradle.properties` file

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_341.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score -2):

please run the follwing command:

```
gralde clean --stacktrace
```

and you will know why

good luck.