# libGDX - Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: gradle, gwt, libgdx, gradlew

When trying to build my libGDX game for HTML, or running [:superDev](https://libgdx.com/wiki/html5-backend-and-gwt-specifics) I get this error :

```
Configure project :html
GWT version is < 2.5 -> additional dependencies are not added.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come   from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':html'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/dependencies/DependencyFactory$ClassPathNotation`
```

I can't even run `gradle html:clean` without this error occurring.

When trying to debug this I updated my version of gradle which caused more things to break, like `gradle desktop:run` unless I completely comment out the html build actions and configs from gradle.

Here are my build.gradle dependencies :

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:1.11.0'
    classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.19'
    classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7'
    classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.16'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

Searching for similar issues has not turned up anything besides aligning the SDK versions which doesn't really make sense here. I went ahead and tried aligning the gdxVersion/gwtVersion between the html/build.gradle and root build.gradle.

**../build.gradle**

```
..
allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "tileShipGame"
    gdxVersion = '1.11.0'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.16'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
    aiVersion = '1.8.2'
    gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
}
..
```

**../html/build.gradle**

```
gwt {
gwtVersion='1.11.0' // Should match the gwt version used for building the gwt backend
...
```

This only introduced the additional error line `GWT version is < 2.5 -> additional dependencies are not added.`. Not sure where that 2.5v is coming from.
The solutions for [updating the build dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092162/android-failed-to-notify-project-evaluation-listener) all revolve around android studio, and have nothing to do with the HTML build, and I can't find a way to transmute that solution to the HTML build.

I tried [building a fresh new project](https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/project-generation) to see if the issue was unique to my own build and found that after [removing the mavenLocal()](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6878) repository it also built with the same error.

The only thing I can think of is my GWT version needs to be changed, but that doesn't seem to be a part of the project? Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346966/libgdx-android-studio-unable-to-load-class-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts?rq=2) but this does not really solve the problem, and requests a reversal of the gradle upgrade. Gradle was upgraded after the issue was found, so the upgrade isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for posterity :

Turns out I have multiple issues with my local build and was able to fix the listener issue by, surprise [downgrading my Gradle version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346966/libgdx-android-studio-unable-to-load-class-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts?rq=2)

**gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```

Unfortunately not the end for me, but it got me moving to the next error. Good luck!

*Note*: The gradle shell confirms this as it is still on a later 8 version and reproduces the issue.
If you're wanting to use the shell then you'll need to use the in-project wrapper

```
C:\MyProject> ./gradlew html:build
```